# If by Allah's decree I get a grievous disease should I refuse cure?

Tags: punishment

I am a neo-Muslim, there are still answers I am seeking. Truth be told the journey of finding the truth is odious, however, the benefits far outweigh the meager pains.

Everything that happens to anyone is Allah's decree, so if I get a disease such as cancer, there could be few logical reasons as to why I got the dreaded disease.

1) I was irresponsible or its genetic, i.e it was not by luck.
In that case, rationally I should go for a cure.

2) It was by luck. Unexplained through reason. I am being punished. 
In that case getting a cure means escaping the scourge, should I seek cure in this case? One could argue yes sure, you can repent later or you should have faith in Allah but statistically its very rare that out of the grace of Lord someone is cured or that by repenting later I am doing anything more wise or better.

Should one refuse medication when one believes he is being punished by Allah?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Should one refuse medication when one believes he is being punished by
>   Allah?

Absolutely not.  You should seek any type of medical treatment available.  The Prophet of Allah, Mohamed son of Abdullah said =

> تَدَاوَوْا فَإِنَّ اللَّهَ عَزَّ وَجَلَّ لَمْ يَضَعْ دَاءً إِلاَّ
>   وَضَعَ لَهُ دَوَاءً غَيْرَ دَاءٍ وَاحِدٍ الْهَرَمُ

Translation = **Make use of medical treatment, for Allah has not made a disease without appointing a remedy for it, with the exception of one disease, namely old age.**

[[Sunan Abu Dawud]](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/29/1)

So if you having an illness is Allah's decree, then Allah has also decreed a counter to it.

Islam clearly permits us to do what we can as long as it doesn't cross the boundaries of Deen.

Answer (score 1):

Without references for prove I can say that if you have a disease or an accident or something in that order, you're actually tested by Allah. Allah put you on a test by a disease, an accident, lost of a loved one, failure in career etc. But it doesn't mean you just wait and die without doing something, you rather should put effort to solve your problem. Allahu a'lam.

May Allah make it easy for us Inchallah.